# How to import maven/Eclipse project to IntelliJ with copying files?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have the project, which I was developing with Eclipse/Maven. Now I am trying to import it into IntelliJ. It does well, but the location of the project files does not change. I.e. they are still located inside Eclipse Workspace, but just linked to IntelliJ place.

Is it possible to really *import* a project, i.e. to copy files to new place and delete all Eclipse-specific control files?

Answer (score 2):

Just copy and paster your project folder anywhere and import it with IntelliJ. You can delete the files `.settings` and `.project` which are generated by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to :

```
File->Import Project
```

then you could see it says: ***Select project with existing source*** and listed eclipse down there as shown in below image:

[image]